# Insert echo command into running command line

Tags: batch-file, redirect, cmd

I have `.exe` file that opens up a command window and waits for user input, let's call it `program.exe`.

I would like to automatically insert the user input into that running Program.

For example if I write a batch file using this, I would like to start the program and insert the command entered by the user into the command line of the started program.

```
@echo off
call program.exe
echo command1
```

This would start the program and "simulate" the input of command1 into the command line of the opened program.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: *maybe* `echo command1|program.exe`. Whether it works or not depends on how exactly the `.exe` is programmed.

Comment: Tryed, but this doesn' work. Also I have more then just a single comand that I would like to execute in sequence. I do not need a single batch I would also be fine with just starting the exe and then running a batch that redirect the text into the open cmd window from that exe file. (like a recorded macro)

Comment: more than one could be done with `(echo command1&echo command2)|program.exe`. But when a single input doesn't work, multiple inputs won't work as well. For your second idea, that can't be done with `cmd` alone. The help of another language, which has some sort of `SendKey` command is needed (like for example `vbs`)

Comment: Okay. I will use autoIT for that purpose. It works. Thanks for input

Comment: another approach `program.exe<command.txt`  where `command.txt` holds comand1 or whatever, proved that `program exe` accepts such input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use powershell to start the application and pass the command:

```
$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$psi.FileName = "proogram.exe"
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false
$psi.RedirectStandardInput = $true
$p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)
Start-Sleep -s 2 #wait 2 seconds so that the process can be up
$p.StandardInput.WriteLine("command1")
```

Comment: I will try this. This is exactly what I am looking for.